# Swallowing Multiple Grenades

Tags: biology, weapons, super-powers, explosions

Okay, there's a character who is force-fed multiple grenades. The resulting explosion does severe damage to their body, but doesn't completely destroy them, and their healing factor fixes all of the damage. Their chest is split open by the combined explosive force. 40 live grenades are inserted into their digestive tract, all throughout. Their size and shape is similar to that of a human. The question is, how durable would they have to be in order to not be completely reduced to a bloody splatter? Let's work with grenades with a blast radius of 9.14 m each.

Comment: Does "flexible" count as "durable"?

Comment: There isn't a "durability metric". Your character either is or is not durable enough to survive, which is entirely up to you.

Comment: He is dead. 40 grenades. The shrapnel alone would shred his body into too many pieces.

Comment: You're asking for a character that needs to be capable of surviving after swallowing 40 grenades, getting blown up from the inside out, being able to regenerate all damage done by both the grenades' explosions as well as all of the shrapnel turning what it finds into minced meat, and all of that with only his torso being damaged?  You're essentially asking for someone as tough, if not tougher, than [Alex Mercer](https://prototype.fandom.com/wiki/Alex_Mercer) from prototype. It's easier to just boost up his healing power so he can heal from a meat puddle in record time.

Comment: Does this character have unusually large throat, or the grenades are unusually small?

Comment: a block of metal wouldn't withstand that, much less a human

Comment: Being flexible would help, and I'm looking for strength. And she's an superpowered alien. The grenades are normal-sized, as well as the insides.

Comment: Maybe the alien has a very corrosive stomach acid catalyst by the super duper whooper unique enzymes that can dissolve anything metal and gunpowder within a blink of an eye ;D

Comment: Hmmm, I'll think about that.

Answer (score 2):

**11 FTSG.**

Most humans have a durability on the order of 0.01- 0.02 FTSG units.  A durability of even 0.1 FTSG suggests a metahuman and a durability of 1 FTSG implies nonorganic biology or divine nature.  One might expect FTSG durability rating to track directly with number of grenades an entity can swallow.  But an entity with a durability of 3 FTSG might actually tolerate the swallowing of 5 or 6 grenades.  An entity with durability of 11 FTSG can actually swallow (or be forced to swallow) whatever number of grenades its internal capacity will allow, as this degree of durability against grenade-type energies means that additional grenades do not increase damage produced.

11 FTSG is the theoretical maximum although of course all entities with durability of 11 FTSG are not equally durable.  One must switch to other measures to compare durability of such entities, such as the FTSAB scale.

Comment: I tried looking up FTSG, and all I found was about skin grafts. And I don't know anything about the FTSAB scale. Can you please explain what they mean in a way I'd understand?

Comment: It is the :"Forced To Swallow Grenade" scale.  And for those made of the sternest stuff, "Forced To Swallow Atomic Bomb" scale.

Comment: Okay, that will be a new unit. And how many FTSGs is one FTSAB, if we ignored that 11 FTSG cap?

Comment: @TysonDennis - thinking about anime type rules, if you have an entity which can SG it might not matter if it is 10 or 100 so FTSG does not scale up to FTSAB.  Really you should probably have other scales between FTSG and FTSAB I think.  The whole premise seems like something out of One Punch Man, and they would probably have 6 or 7 intermediate scales for purposes of monster / hero categorization.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's my answer (come up with yours if you can estimate things better). As each grenade contains .052 kg of TNT, that's equal to 2.08 kg of TNT, which explode with the energy of 8.70 MJ combined. The explosion would be producing 1000 psi of overpressure at a distance of 1 m, which is enough to kill a person 50 times over. But it's at point-blank range. If we work with a minimum distance of .015 m, then we have up to 44 times the pressure, which would be about 44444 psi, or 306 MPa. That's getting pretty close to triple the pressure of Challenger Deep. The weaker points of the body would be the ones taking the most damage.

The human ribs are at minimum 29.9 mm^2, or 2.99*10^-5 m^2. We can use that to as our estimate. And as there's 24 ribs, that means that we have a total area of 7.18*10^-4 m^2. The force of the explosives would be 220 kN. That's like 66.6 (hehehe) times that needed to crack a human rib, so her bones are clearly a good amount stronger than human bones. Now, there's the shrapnel. Grenade shrapnel can travel up to 7.9 km/s, and her tissue seems to all be a higher quality than human tissue. Let's work with a fragment of .02 kg as an example. It would hold 624 kJ of kinetic energy, and as her skeleton is stronger, it would probably stop most shrapnel from hitting her brain.

Plus, her muscular structure is still recognizable, which should put her muscles at maximum 4441 times stronger than human muscles. Let's settle for 4400 times stronger. That way, there's some damage, but not catastrophic. And that should at least partially help with shrapnel. And then, there's the whole business with the momentum. Let's go with a digestive system of 35 m^2, so there's a total force of 10.7 GN. If we assume that the explosion lasts for 9 ms, and as she weighs 105.8 kg, that means that if the explosives were perfect at imparting momentum into her, she'd find herself flying backwards at 912 km/s.

And that's ignoring equivalent exchange. If we go with all of the energy going into propelling her backwards, we've got an initial velocity of 406 m/s. That's Mach speed, and she'd be forced onto a parabolic path by lift, before rapidly losing speed to drag and falling into the snowdrift. Thankfully, she's been travelling at supersonic speeds for millennia, and is used to that kind of stuff. But that is still a lot of damage, and she would've died right there and then if not for her healing factor. Swallowing one live grenade would mess you up, and even if you were comparable to Superman, swallowing 40? And that's terrible.